# Accessing Keys and Values of a List of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am using a list in Python to store dictionaries with recipe ingredients as keys and the amount of each ingredient as the value for each dictionary. For example;

```
Ingredients = [{'Pizza Base' : 'Medium Size'}, {'Cheese' : '200g'}, {'Sauce' : '200g'}]
```

How do I access each ingredient and the amount?

I know how to access each dictionary in the list, but I don't know how to access the values in each dictionary.

Comment: Why do you have separate dictionaries in a list? Just merge them and have one.

Comment: There are use cases for multiple dicts in a list, but this is not one of them. You should have a single dict.

Comment: @DanielRoseman A list of lists instead?

Comment: Why not *just a dict*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
Ingredients = [{'Pizza Base' : 'Medium Size'}, {'Cheese' : '200g'}, {'Sauce' : '200g'}]
for ing in Ingredients:
  name = list(ing.keys())[0]
  amount = ing[name]
  print(name,':',amount)
```

The above outputs :

```
Pizza Base : Medium Size
Cheese : 200g
Sauce : 200g
```

Comment: Absolutely Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thanks.